# Unity or Unreal Engine with Blender?

Tags: game-engine, export

Im interested in creating low poly mesh and exporting them to a game engine. Which game engine is better to use, Unity or Unreal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one of them. This are the 2 most used game engines and Blender can easily export mesh, textures, animations, for each one of them.

Comment: Cool Thankyou, I guess it’s also easy to add textures and things too.